# What has it to do

Tags: grammar

**What has it to do with selfishness and altruism ?**
Is this sentence grammatically correct ?
Shouldn't it be **What does it have to do with selfishness and altruism**

Answer (score 2):

Both are possible in British English.

Forming a question by inversion with the verb "have" (when it isn't an auxiliary verb)is rarer, and perhaps old fashioned. It is more common in British English, perhaps especially with rhetorical questions:

> Have you any idea what this would cost?

Simple direct questions are less likely to use this:

> Have you a pen? → Do you have a pen?

Comment: I use the inversion quite a lot, unless I am trying to tone down my way of speaking to avoid odd looks, especially from younger people. Also simple 'have' shortened, e.g. I've no change for the bus.

Comment: Michael, you are rarer and perhaps old fashioned (and I mean that lovingly)

Comment: I think it comes from having a Cockney mother and a Midlands father, and being sent to a posh school at the age of 11. My Lancashire born wife calls me 'Lord Henry', but living with me (and in Bristol) for 30 years has affected her so that when she goes back to Wigan all her old pals say she's become a 'southern Jessie'.