# Do people say "have you enough room for me?" in British English?

Tags: phrase-usage, american-english, british-english

I heard some British people say "have you enough room for me?"

It is like a wrong grammar usage, but **is it an idiom in British English?**

Does that mean "do you have enough room for me?"

**Do American people say it that way?**

Comment: Have you searched this site for similar questions? (E.g.: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/309690/what-has-it-to-do/309691)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What has it to do](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/309690/what-has-it-to-do)

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct, but I would be less surprised to hear a British speaker use the first phrasing than I would if I heard an American say it that way.